# The given key is not present in the dictionary

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Hi I am trying to fetch the accounts from CRM 2011. I am fetching the data in the EntityCollection . But when I am trying to read or access data from entityCollection it displayed first record but throwing an error after that record. Kindly have a look to below code and suggest me.

```
  string fetch2 = @"
                          <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform'      mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
      <entity name='account'>
      <attribute name='name' />
      <attribute name='address1_city' />
      <attribute name='primarycontactid' />
      <attribute name='telephone1' />
      <attribute name='accountid' />
      <order attribute='name' descending='false' />
      <filter type='and'>
         <condition attribute='accounttype' operator='eq' value='01' />
     </filter>
     </entity>
     </fetch>";

        try
        {
            EntityCollection fxResult = _service.RetrieveMultiple(new  FetchExpression(fetch2));
            foreach (var e in fxResult.Entities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id:{0},Name:{1},City:{2}", e.Attributes  ["accountid"].ToString(), e.Attributes["name"].ToString(), e.Attributes["address1_city"].ToString());
               // Console.WriteLine("Id:{0},Name:{1},City:{2}", e.ToEntity["accountid"]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:==" + e.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before access an attribute you need to ask if it is in the context:

```
e.Attributes.Contains("address1_city")
```

If the collection contains the attribute, then you can access it safe.

```
string accountid = (string)e.Attributes["address1_city"]
```

The reason the attribute doesn't come in the collection it's because it is null or you are not retrieving it. In this case maybe, one of your attributes is null. Maybe address1_city.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have a attribute of type object and I am unable to get the value from that attribute. As mentioned in your code I am able to check and retrieve the address1_city as it is of type string but I have one more attribute status which of object type. I am trying to check and retrieve it but unable to do that. Please suggest

Comment: If you have an attribute like "Status Code" you have to cast it as "OptionSetValue"

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving attribute values of late-bound `Entity` objects, the recommended approach is to use method `getAttributeValue<T>`. When the attribute is not present in the entity's attribute collection, it returns `default(T)`.

The primary key ('id') of the record is always present when it is returned by the OrganizationService.

So your code should look like this:

```
EntityCollection fxResult = _service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch2));

foreach (var e in fxResult.Entities)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Id:{0},Name:{1},City:{2}",
        e.Id,
        e.GetAttributeValue<string>("name"),
        e.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_city"));
}
```

You can safely use the item selector when you need to assign a value to an attribute, regardless if it is already present or not.

E.g. the following code line is valid:

```
e["name"] = "Demo Accountname";
```

Comment: You have to take care with the default values that getAttributeValue<T> returns. It's better to handle what to do when the key is not present than handle the default values.

Comment: I disagree. Following that approach will soon make your code verbose and hard to read and maintain. In most cases working with nullable types does the job well enough.

Comment: Default values for DateTime, decimal and bool are not null

Comment: Default values for nullable types are (like DateTime?, int? etc.). Also, attribute values retrieved or queried from IOrganizationService are not in the attribute collection when they are null in the database. That's another reason why in many scenarios it makes little sense to test if an attribute is present in the entity's attributes collection.

Comment: `DateTime? date = entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("nofield");` will bring `{01/01/0001 12:00:00 a.m.}`, making someone try to see what's wrong with the date

Comment: `var date = entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime?>("nofield")` on the other hand will work perfectly in most cases. Remember we are working here with the so called *late bound* entity approach. When it comes to writing serious amounts of business logic, I would recommend working with strong typed entity classes. That minimizes the risk of typos.

Comment: Nevertheless a useful discussion added to this topic! It addresses a rather common misconception when working with entities in Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Thanks for helping correct that misconception.  If you need help generating Early Bound Entities Use this: https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/